# Is there a Cut & Paste as New Class File (Macro)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-macros

I'm looking for a free Visual Studio feature, extension or macro. that can help with the following situation.

When I prototype I tend to keep all my classes in one file (bad practice I know, but yeah it a  prototype). Then comes the point the where the files is too hard to navigate. So I breakout the classes into separate files inside the project, the folder structure reflecting the namespaces.
To achieve the is;-
 1. Add new Folder
 2. Add new Class
 3. Name class
 4. Cut and paste corresponding section into new class file.

For me, Steps 2 through 4 are prime fodder for a new Menu entries.

Cut Class as New Class File
 Cut as New Partial Class File.

I've seen this feature in C# but not VB.net.

So does know any how to achieve this for VB.net?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a macro that does what you want in C#... looking at the code it's probably fairly straight forward to modify it to work in VB...

http://plisky.net/main/macros/documentation

Also, I'm pretty sure all the commercial refactoring tools (Resharper, CodeRush, etc.) support this...

Comment: Seem to be stuck in looping want this function to return true.

`code`
    Private Function AttemptToAddCSFile(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim pi = DTE.ItemOperations.AddNewItem("Visual Basic Items\Code\Class", name + ".vb")
            Return True
        Catch ex As COMException
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
`code`

Comment: I use resharper and I almost exclusively use it for this refactoring,  this is awesome!

Comment: Thanks for posting the link Scrappydog, the macros now live on a new domain so have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this using [Move Type to Another File or Namespace](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Move_Type_to_Another_File_or_Namespace)

Comment: Resharper isn't free, like I stated in the question. It doesn't support vb 2010 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this and can point you to an updated version of the macro that scrappy kindly linked.  Its at http://plisky.net/main/plisy.net-visual-studio-productivity-macros.

If you still want it and wish to test it for VB I can happily make the changes to support VB.net but as I don't use VB I'd need a tester :)  As its a while since this post you probably have something working already though.